# UIScrollview addSubviews (dynamically) during scroll leads to jitter

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, image, uiscrollview

I am building an iOS application which actually display images on a scrollview (from top to bottom), images are being displayed one below the another. But the problem I am running into is, when user scrolls the view upto some extent (half the size of scrollview) then I try to add more image views at the bottom of the scrollview (during scroll) but this leads to a lag in the scrollview scrolling. Is there a way to add views on the scrollview on scroll without this lag/jitter effect?

Many Thanks,

Reno Jones

Comment: You are loading the images from URL?

Comment: Sure there 'is do it in another thread..

Comment: yes, these images are downloaded asynchronously on a background thread and then resized as well through code and then passed to the imageviews that are added on the scrollview. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The very reason is this **lag/jitter effect** might be a lot of UI work being done on main thread while scroll view is being scrolled. This can also be seen while scrolling a table view where some images are being shown (If these images are downloaded from some remote  server then this **lag/jitter effect** increases many folds)

What you can do here is reusing your  Imageviews or Image containers (some custom view that holds your imageview).

a) You can create all these custom views/Imageviews at load time and update there content as and when Scrollview is scrolled.

b) Create the scroll view along with content at one go. (This included fetching the images to be shown)

In case the images are loaded from Server then you would surely like to have a look at one of the samples named [LazyLoading](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)

Hope it helps !!!

Comment: Thanks for the reply though. I cannot create so many subviews or containers at the loadtime or in one go. I have around 400+ images, and out of which I try to draw 25 imageviews at a time and add them on scrollview and let those imageviews register to the image, once image is downloaded and cached then it is being displayed on the imageview for which the image is associated with main thread.

Comment: You can take a hint from - http://blog.slaunchaman.com/2011/02/28/cocoa-touch-tutorial-using-grand-central-dispatch-for-asynchronous-table-view-cells/ as well

Comment: Thanks - I am already using GCD for async image downloading and I have written a category to download on the background gcd thread and pass the image to the mainthread when downloaded successfully :)